# Gallery Image Numbers?

Tags: gallery, images

Is there a way, in an image gallery, to display what number the image is in the gallery in the image.php template?  I'd like to incorporate this into my next / previous button area.

For example, if I'm on the first image out of twenty it would say "1 of 20".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
global $post;
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);

$photos = get_children(array(
  'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
  'post_parent'    => array_shift($ancestors),
));

$index = 0;
foreach($photos as $photo){
  $index++;
  if($photo->ID === $post->ID) break;
}

printf('%d out of %d', $index, count($photos));
```

Comment: Is there a way to reverse which numbers are assigned to the images?  For example, 1 of 4 should actually be 4 of 4.  Take a look: http://themeforward.com/demo2/features/gallery-2/

Comment: try adding `$photos = array_reverse($photos);`